# Comparing Lucene Indices

Tags: java, lucene

I have an application that reads some input files and updates a lucene index (I am using lucene-core-3.6.0.). I have two separate builds of this application (Build A and Build B), I want to ensure that the builds produce the same artifacts when given the same starter index and same input.

What I've done so far is taken the existing index and made two copies of it (Index A and Index B). I then ran Build A on Index A which results in an updated Index (Index A_u). I ran Build B on Index B which results in an updated Index (Index B_u).

How can I compare these two separate lucene indices (Index A_u and Index B_u) to ensure the indexes are the same? I've done a diff and have noticed difference but I'm not sure that it entails that the indexes don't contain the same information.

Comment: How far does this validation need to go?  Do you just need to verify that the same content is *stored* in the index?  Or do you need to confirm the same terms are indexed?  Do you need to verify other details like docfreqs, termvectors, norms, etc?